# How to prove that CDF (Cumulative distribution functions) is right continuous and monotone increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution

Definition of monotone increasing:

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing (respectively, monotone decreasing) if for any $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_{1} \leq x_{2},$ it is true that $f\left(x_{1}\right) \leq f\left(x_{2}\right)$ (respectively, $\left.f\left(x_{1}\right) \geq f\left(x_{2}\right)\right)$.

Definition of Right-Continuous:

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is right-continuous at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if for every sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset(x, \infty)$ such that $x_{n} \geq x_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n}=x,$ it is true that
$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f\left(x_{n}\right)=x .$

Let, the c.d.f. of a $\operatorname{Unif}((a, b))$ -distributed random variable is
$$
F_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0, & x \in(-\infty, a] \\
\frac{x-a}{b-a}, & x \in(a, b) \\
1, & x \in[b, \infty)
\end{array}\right.
$$

How to prove that the above CDF (Cumulative distribution functions) is right continuous and monotone increasing? Is the c.d.f. FX also left-continuous?

Comment: right-continuity follows from the continuity from above of a measure, and the increasing property also follow from the increasing property of a measure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why distribution function is right continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514135/why-distribution-function-is-right-continuous)

Comment: It might be helpful to plot the graph of $F_X$.